# Why would this question on all a 4-digit French phone number from the US be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question [How can I call a 4-digit French phone number from the US?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12137/164) received 4  off-topic close votes. Why would this question be off-topic?

---

Copying the question here in case it gets removed:

> [How can I call a 4-digit French phone number from the US?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12137/164)
>
> My French bank (Caisse d'Epargne Île de France) wants me to call them
>   at `3241`. I'm currently in the United States. How can I reach such a
>   phone number from the US?
>
> (Assume that the bank doesn't have a 10-digit French phone number, in
>   which case I could just add `+33` and remove the `0`)

Comment: Note: until it's not closed, it's not closed. Personally I believe it's borderline on topic, as it does affect expats more than locals